# How can I solve sequence is not defined in actions class protractor

Tags: angularjs, automation, protractor, action, sequence

[COUNTY HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8Udt.png)my action class to click looks like this:

```
var mail=element(by.xpath('//span[@class="mat-select-placeholder ng- tns- 
c44-174 ng-star-inserted"][text()="Country"]'));
browser.actions();

browser.actions.mouseMove(mail);
browser.actions.click().perform();
browser.sleep('3000');
var subMenu=element(by.xpath('//span[@class="mat-option-text"][text()="United States"]'));
subMenu.click();
browser.sleep('6000');
```

While executing throws:

> Message: Failed: sequence is not defined Stack: ReferenceError: sequence is not defined

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
<span class="mat-select-placeholder ng-tns-c34-236 ng-star-inserted" style="">Country</span>
```

United States 
[us HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Xhc.png) [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okyEz.png)

Comment: If you drop one action after another, does it continue at some point? Can you also post a bit of that HTML?

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk  yes.To select US ,First I need to click on Country.only after clicking I will see options and I need to click first one to select US

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk  <mat-option _ngcontent-c33="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted mat-active" role="option" ng-reflect-value="230" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-1659" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"

Comment: I assume it's a select. Can you edit your post with your code and format it? You don't really specify what should be clicked. You should write something like: mail.click(); subMenu.click(); You don't have to type browser.actions...

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk I attacjhed HTML pics  https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Xhc.png  https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8Udt.png

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk  I edit locators   did not work for me    var mail= element(by.xpath('//input[@placeholder="Country"]'));
            mail.click();

               var subMenu= element(by.cssContainingText('.mat-option-text', 'United States '));
               subMenu.click();
              browser.sleep('3000');



                browser.sleep('6000');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following?

```
element(by.cssContainingText('span', 'Country')).click();
browser.sleep(3000);
element(by.cssContainingText('mat-option', 'United States')).click();
browser.sleep(6000);
```

Comment: I'm glad I've helped.